# Erro ao consumir Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-web-api

Olá, em um projeto web ASP.NET MVC eu estou tentando consumir uma API que é um projeto Web API, as duas aplicações estão rodando no mesmo servidor.

Quando eu acesso a aplicação MVC ocorre erro quando essa aplicação tenta consumir a Web API, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente 127.0.0.1:24777
 [SocketException (0x274d): Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente 127.0.0.1:24777]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +6641121
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +271

[WebException: Impossível conectar-se ao servidor remoto]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) +2263386
   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +106

[HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
```

Será que pode ser agora timeout da action do Web API?

Comment: Sendo uma SocketException, me parece mesmo ser um problema de conexão àquele endereço/porta (127.0.0.1:24777). Você já testou para ver se o serviço está no ar e pode mesmo ser acessado nessa porta? Tente consumir algum dos serviços usando Postman (www.getpostman.com)? O resultado por lá pode nos ajudar a entender melhor o problema.

Comment: Não tinha mais esse endereço na aplicação, mas no momento da publicação por algum motivo os arquivos não foram substituídos, então apaguei todos os arquivos e colei novamente e parou de ocorrer esse erro, mas agora está ocorrendo este erro: Uma tarefa foi cancelada. Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. Detalhes da Exceção: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Uma tarefa foi cancelada

Comment: Será que pode ser agora timeout da action do Web API?

Answer (score 3):

Edmar, passei por este problema ontem mesmo.

A primeira ação que você precisa tomar é saber em qual endereço a API esta. Pela descrição do erro, seu projeto esta tentando acessá-la em **127.0.0.1:24777**, mas não a encontrou. Isso pode ocorrer por 2 motivos:

1. A API não esta executando. Normalmente, na minha experiência, uso o IP local atribuindo uma porta quando a API esta rodando pelo IIS Express, daí o projeto da API deve ser executado, normalmente, pelo Visual Studio que faz o start do site no IIS Express.
2. O endereço para acessar a API mudou e não é mais 127.0.0.1:24777. Neste caso, você precisa verificar o novo endereço no projeto da API no Visual Studio.

Se tiver ocorrido o motivo 2, você terá que atualizar a configuração de acesso à API no arquivo web.config do seu projeto que acessa a API.

Comment: Não tinha mais esse endereço na aplicação, mas no momento da publicação por algum motivo os arquivos não foram substituídos, então apaguei todos os arquivos e colei novamente e parou de ocorrer esse erro, mas agora está ocorrendo este erro:  Uma tarefa foi cancelada.
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

Detalhes da Exceção: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Uma tarefa foi cancelada.

Comment: Será que pode ser agora timeout da action do Web API?

Comment: Pela descrição, não parece timeout. Já havia acessado essa API antes? Esta em desenvolvimento?